# Can additional iterations of backward induction as described affect optimal policy?

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-processes, markov-process, decision-theory

Consider a game with the following properties:

- Single player
- Finite number of game states (after the player arrives at a terminal state, he or she can begin again from the start state; the player can also voluntarily abandon the game from any state and start over)
- Stochastic (positive and negative rewards are distributed throughout the game at various states and depend on a combination of luck and the player's actions)
- Markov representation is orderly enough to apply backward induction by sweeping the entire state space once

Suppose we perform this backward induction, under the axiom that reaching a terminal state or voluntarily starting over has an expected value of $0$, and conclude that being at the start state has a positive expected value.  We might then try performing one or more additional iterative sweeps through the state space, replacing these axiomatic $0$'s with the expected value of the start state calculated in the first iteration.

My hypothesis (based on a non-public study of a particular game) is that at each state, these additional iterations can only increase the expected values of the possible actions by equal amounts, thus never changing the first iteration's optimal action prescription for any state and being irrelevant to the final policy.  However it's not clear that this result should hold or why it does.  Is this conclusion correct?  If not in general, what additional game rules or conditions must be specified to make it so?